How to change the Windows Cursor on net maui?
Well, I'm trying to find a way to make the Windows cursor invisible or change its appearance, but CoreWindow is null.
var window = App.Current.MainPage.GetParentWindow().Handler.PlatformView as MauiWinUIWindow;
window.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);

How to change the appearance of Windows on Net Maui?

You can also refer to the offical doc: Handlers.

You can refer to this case: Maui How to show cursor as pointer on Windows? and download the project: MauiCursor. Add the following code in MainPage.xaml.cs:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hover.IsVisible = true;
        Hover.SetCustomCursor(CursorIcon.Wait, Hover.Handler?.MauiContext);
        CursorBehavior.SetCursor(CounterBtn, CursorIcon.SizeAll);
    }
    
    //add this
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
        this.SetCustomCursor(CursorIcon.IBeam, this.Handler?.MauiContext);
    }
}

It can change the appearance of cursor to IBeam(The "I"-shaped Windows cursor used for text selection). I tested it and it works well.
In addition, if you want to custom icon of cursor, you can refer to this: CoreCursor Class / Remarks and modify here.
